# How can I resolve a database name to a directory?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am connected to a database `foo`, and I want to resolve where the underlying directory is for that database, what are my options? Obviously I can reason from `datadir`, and the database name but there are problems with that: it requires me to implement my own [`encode`](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-utilities/blob/08276b2258bf9739f53406b354b21195ff69a261/mysql/utilities/common/tools.py#L474) function to [map identifiers to file names.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-mapping.html). Which is [encoding-dependant](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8e797a5d6eb3a87f16498edcb7261a75897babae/sql/sql_table.cc#L631).

This encoding process is mandatory, the database `foo._234-asdf` maps to data directory `/var/lib/mysql/foo@002e_234@002dasdf`.

Is there a supported way to query the data-directory **for a specific database**, or for the connected database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a better way of doing this than rolling my own routine. Currently, I am using this perl code:

```
s/(\W)/sprintf('@%04x', ord $1)/eg;
```

Comment: That works for your example; I wonder if it always works.  The `@002e` smells like a Unicode codepoint, but with `@` instead of `U+` or `0x`.  I'll guess that an emoji in the database name may be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

To know which database you session is connected to, fire below query :

```
mysql> select database();
+---------------+
| database()    |
+---------------+
| foo       |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

To fetch path for traversing to schema directory, output from below query can be used :

```
select concat(VARIABLE_VALUE, database())  from performance_schema.global_variables where variable_name='datadir'; 
+------------------------------------+
| concat(VARIABLE_VALUE, database()) |
+------------------------------------+
| /var/lib/mysql/foo             |
+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This is not correct. Create a database called `.-OWNED-.`

Comment: @EvanCarroll - then put that in the Question and emphasize that you have naughty characters in the database name.

Comment: @RickJames ok... updated.